# UTC date format for momentjs

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am using momentjs on npm and I am using it to format a date for an api i am trying to use.

The format I am trying to replicate from the api example is this: `2020-03-21T13:13:30Z`

I am aware of the .format() option in its documentation but I am not sure what to input into it.

Comment: That looks like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, you could use `utc` function and leave `format` as is like this:

```js
let date = moment().utc().format();
console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```